# Bootstrap form-horizontal vertical alignment of checkboxes without label text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I have changed from Bootstrap 3.0.0 to 3.2.0 this morning because I needed some of the new features for my web application. Everything seemed to work as expected until I observed an issue with the vertical alignment of checkboxes in a `.form-horizontal` form.

An example is available at http://www.bootply.com/AYN64feYze. The markup for this minimum example is:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">With label text</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> label text
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Without label text</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox">
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If a checkbox has no following text it is shifted below the row it should appear in.

Is there a solution to this problem? Since I already have the leading label I do not need a following text for my checkboxes. My current workaround is adding text to the `<label>` that contains the `<input type="checkbox">` and use the background color as the font color to hide the text.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will affect the rest of your form layout, but the issue seems to be resolved if you change the display attribute of `<label>` (currently set to `inline-block`) to:

```
label{
    display:inline;
}
```

Here's an [updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FssaYf0PrH). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great answer. I was able to incorporate it into my CSS by adding a class for "empty" checkboxes. By using `.checkbox-empty label {display:inline}` I can apply the new style to all checkboxes that have no text without affecting other checkboxes or labels. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label class="pull-right" for="MyCheckBox">My Checkbox</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <input type="checkbox" name="MyCheckBox">
    </div>
</div>
```

First, I had to remove the `<div class='checkbox'>` element.  I then made the following changes to the checkbox label element:

1. Place the label in its own column div `<div class="col-lg-3"></div>`
2. Remove class="control-label"
3. Add class="pull-right".

I ended up with a checkbox that aligned with the other inputs horizontally and with its label vertically.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a solution as well and an easy one, too. Thanks for sharing. I made a bootply as a demo of your solution http://www.bootply.com/cCSKDNvW7O.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need following text for the checkboxes, why not just remove the `<label>` surrounding the checkboxes. Like so.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="check1">With label text</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="check2">Without label text</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="check2">
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code appeared to work in your Bootply when I tried it.

And remember if you have a label to use the `for` attribute for screen readers and to make it easier for your users (they can just click the label instead of the checkbox).

Comment: Yes, this markup works, but the checkboxes will not be aligned with other input elements (e.g. `<input type="text" />`). To align the checkboxes you have to remove `<div class="checkbox">` too. See [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/TRrjsvu3X8). The bootply shows the incorrect horizontal alignment when you just remove the `<label>` tag and the correct alignment when you remove both, the `<label>` and the `<div class="checkbox">` tags. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer and reminding me of the `for` attribute ;)