# Bootstrap left align checkbox in horizontal form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. I have a horizontal form with a label-less checkbox, like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="max-width:600px">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field1">Field 1:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="field1"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field2">Field 2:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="field2"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field3">Field 3:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <!-- HERE IS THE CHECKBOX: -->
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="field3"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" type="submit">Apply Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I've created a [Bootply demo here](http://www.bootply.com/R7RmWErF5y).

The problem is the checkbox is centered. I wanted it to be left aligned, so the left edge is aligned with the left edge of the text inputs above it.

How do I do that?

I have tried:

- Adding class `text-left` to the div that contains the checkbox (result: no effect).
- Removing the grid width specifiers from the checkbox div (result: it just ends up on the next line).
- Enclosing the checkbox input in a `label` tag, a wild guess after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912377/bootstrap-form-horizontal-vertical-alignment-of-checkboxes-without-label-text) (result: it disappears).
- Random hand-wavey rearrangements of divs (result: spirit crushed, git checkout to revert changes).

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can you add a class to the checkbox? Try this:

```
<input class="form-control move-left" type="checkbox" id="field3">

.move-left {
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/At8YVfnm5F

**Updated** as per gyre's comment.

Comment: Excellent. I guess I would've discovered that the width was the culprit if I had looked closer in the inspector. This also gets rid of the shadow border, which actually was bothering me even though I didn't ask about it.

Comment: Also (thanks gyre), [adding the `checkbox-inline` class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081275/bootstrap-left-align-checkbox-in-horizontal-form/41081354#comment69368941_41081343) on top of this fixes the vertical alignment as well.

Comment: One other thing: `width: auto` would be a more flexible choice.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the width initial or auto for the input id [LiveOnBootplay](http://www.bootply.com/R7RmWErF5y)

```
   input#field3 {
     width: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the class of the div enclosing your checkbox from `col-sm-8` to `col-sm-1` and then added a class of `checkbox-inline` to your input element.

**Demo:** http://www.bootply.com/kjF1gVtWDC

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <!-- HERE IS THE CHECKBOX: -->
  <input class="form-control checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" id="field3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I see. I guess that works as long 1/12th the container width is less than the form row's height, which is true in my 600px case. I kinda regret adding max-width to my example but it's too late, heh. I wonder if there's a solution for wider forms? Also the vertical alignment is a bit off (it's a few pixels low) but I suppose I can live with that for now.

Comment: @JasonC The vertical alignment being off is caused by `margin: 4px 0 0;` - in playing around with your fiddle, could modify its css properties in the developer console. and the line height.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cool, setting `margin:0` fixes that. This gets the job done. I'm gonna give this a few minutes still to see if anybody has any suggestions for cases with wider parent containers before I accept it.

Comment: @JasonC I'm a "bootstrapper" myself. I don't want to take away from this answer but if I can be of help, I certainly will be happy to help. I'm not on my working machine right now.

Comment: Note that you can apply a class of `checkbox-inline` to the input to achieve the same effect.